# Can't seem to get rid of pesky syntax errors

Tags: sql, excel, vba, syntax-error

So I'm a bit new to SQL coding, and my company has a pre-existing Purchase Order system, run off a .xlsx macro enabled sheet.

I keep getting "Incorrect syntax near "," and when I change a random comma here or there, I get *different* errors. When It throws the errors and I hot debug, it highlights the `SetRS = Conn.Execute(SQL)` line

So does anything stand out to everyone's better trained eyes?
Thanks!

```vb
Dim Report As Worksheet
Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet
SQL = "insert into Purchases.dbo.POs values(" & Range("H12").Value & "," & Range("H30").Value & Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Report.Range("F16:F29")) & "," & Range("A34").Value & _
"','" & Range("F7").Value & "','" & Range("C12").Value & "','" & Range("A38").Value & "',0,'" & Code & "')"
'MsgBox SQL
Set RS = Conn.Execute(SQL)
```

Comment: Can you just print out what the SQL statement would be? You can either inspect the variable in the debugger or print it in the immediate window

Comment: I would break down the long SQL string into helper variables, then you can see them more clearly whilst debugging. Are there any commas in the values within the excel cells e.g cell H12? Or are any blank?

Comment: Can you include the output from 'MsgBox SQL'? Also, what DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, etc...) are you using?

Comment: As other's are pointing out, it's impossible to say what the error is. It's 100% definitely coming from your `SQL = ` line. Please remove the comment on your `MsgBox SQL` line and share what pops up in that messagebox. Alternatively, you could use `debug.print SQL` and copy/paste from the "Immediate" pane. The SQL that your code is writing is wrong and that's where we must look for errors, but without seeing the result, we are blind.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma between the two : Range("H30").Value & Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Report.Range("F16:F29")) ?

Comment: Personally, for testing I would add your "SQL = " construction into a new column in the worksheet, just for troubleshooting. Once you have it right you can move it into VBA. Copy everything after SQL (including the equal sign) and paste into the last column of your spreadsheet, and that should give you a string representation of your query. Easier to troubleshoot in the sheet than in VBA.

Comment: @Error_2646 `Database.schema.Table`, must be SQL Server.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Ah, yeah that's right. Didn't catch the 'dbo'

Comment: Are there strings in any of the fields you include? If yes, you will have to pass string literals. (N'... ' for NVARCHAR and '... ' for VARCHAR) if there are strings containing an apostrophe, you will have to double it to escape it.

Comment: `Range("H30").Value` is concatenated with the result of `WorksheetFunction.Sum` ...is that intended? You need to compare your actual `SQL` string with the *expected* SQL command. `Debug.Print SQL` works wonders for that. Ctrl+G to bring up the debug pane.

Comment: You probably want an opening apostrophe for the value you get from A34 since you have a closing one.

Answer (score 2):

As you're experiencing, cramming as many operations as possible in a single instruction makes the code harder to read and debug.

That said I'm 95% sure this `Range("H30").Value & Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Report.Range("F16:F29"))` is not what you intended to be doing.

Break it down:

```vb
Dim value1 As Double
value1 = ActiveSheet.Range("H12").Value

Dim value2 As String
value2 = "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("H30").Value & "'"

Dim value3 As Double
value3 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Report.Range("F16:F29"))

Dim value4 As Double
value4 = ActiveSheet.Range("A34").Value

Dim value5 As String
value5 = "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("F7").Value & "'"

Dim value6 As String
value6 = "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value & "'"

Dim value7 As String
value7 = "'" & ActiveSheet.Range("A38").Value & "'"

Dim value8 As Long
value8 = 0

Dim value9 As String
value9 = "'" & Code & "'"
```

Now you can validate every value individually. All good? Now concatenate them:

```vb
Dim values As Variant
values = Join(Array(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9), ",")

Dim sql As String
sql = "insert into Purchases.dbo.POs values(" & values & ")"
```

Does the SQL string look right?

```vb
Debug.Print sql
Stop 'hit Ctrl+G to bring up the *immediate pane* and view the output
```

If you take that output and run it in SSMS, does the insert work? Yeah? Then you're good to go!

```vb
conn.Execute sql
```

---

Now, say `ActiveSheet.Range("H30").Value` contains a malicious string; executing it directly off the connection like this is going to make the `insert` statement fail, and SQL Server will happily execute the executable SQL statement that was carelessly concatenated into the query: [this comes to mind](https://xkcd.com/327/), lookup "SQL injection" for more information.

Look into how you can use an `ADODB.Command` with a `ADODB.Parameter` for each value, and instantly avoid this security vulnerability. It also shields your code from producing an invalid SQL statement when the value contains, say, a `'` single quote - and as a bonus you no longer need to care for surrounding strings with single quotes, the server will handle it.

Comment: I did not know that you didn't need a fields list.  BTW,  capitalizing the SQL keywords would be better :)

Comment: @TinMan the field names can be omitted if the number of values (and their types) matches the table structure (PK/identity column can be omitted, assuming `identity insert` is off). Also... SCREAMCASE makes my eyes bleed ;-)

Comment: I guess you can't be right about everything.. at least proper case them!...lol

Comment: @TinMan eh, `void DoSomething()\n{\t/*code*/\n}` wins over `void DoSomething() {\n\t/*code*/\n}`, too ;-)

Comment: Awww..RegEx makes my Eyes bleed!!  I am going to add this to my arsonal: [How to get rid of Syntax Errors Fast](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17X7px0Zbbd5rclXexnt3tBtQXYJvhHgK).

Comment: @TinMan not regex, just a failed attempt to depict line breaks and indents/tabs in a SO comment :)

Comment: I had RegEx on my mind.  I've been thinking about writing a JSON Decoder/Encoder to better learn it.  Agh..I missed the subtle placement of `/n`.  Hmm...JSlint and [csharp viewer beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer) disagree.  I was unsure so I checked look under the hood of the Duck.  Yeah I agree it looks cleaner.  int FormatBrackets()\n{\t/*return +1*/\n}

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for your help but it seems like there is so much wrong with this code, that I'll need to ask a *new* question and post the entire code. SSMS is just bleeding red with this.

Comment: @RMathis watch the single quotes. Notice how the above code makes it easy to spot where they are and where they might be missing, without parsing through a concatenated SQL command: value is `As String`, its assignment begins and ends with a `"'"` single quote. If your values actually *contain* single quotes, either you need to escape them (double them up), or do things the right way and use actual `ADODB.Parameter`s.

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilders have an AppendFormat function that makes it easy to create SQL Statements.

[StringBuilder.AppendFormat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Appends the string returned by processing a composite format string, which contains zero or more format items, to this instance. Each format item is replaced by the string representation of a corresponding object argument.

Note: The VBA uses StringBuilder.AppendFormat_4 to processes the format string and an Array of values.

> ```vb
> StringBuilder.AppendFormat_4 Format, Array()
> ```

```vb
Const Code = 10
Dim sb As Object
Dim SQL As String
Dim Report As Worksheet
Set Report = Excel.ActiveSheet

Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
SQL = "INSERT INTO Purchases.DBO.Pos VALUES({0},'{1}',{2},'{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}',0,'{7}')"
sb.AppendFormat_4 SQL, Array(Range("H12").Value, _
                           Range("H30").Value, _
                           Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("F16:F29")), _
                           Range("A34").Value, _
                           Range("F7").Value, _
                           Range("C12").Value, _
                           Range("A38").Value, _
                           Code)

SQL = sb.ToString
```

IMO. capitalizing SQL keywords makes the SQL Statement easier to read.  I would also supply add a fields list yo the statement.

> ```vb
> INSERT INTO Purchases.DBO.Pos(FirstName,LastName) VALUES('Tin','Man')
> ```

Comment: Sucks that the `AppendFormat` method doesn't take a `params` final parameter; if it were the case then the `Array(...)` call would be superfluous. +1 for a cleaner way (thought the overloading support is... meh) to concatenate values into an SQL string, however it should be noted that concatenating values into any executable SQL statement is wrong and dangerous ;-)